# CORS issue: Getting error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" when it actually is

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, http, cors

I doubt the backend serving my app is important, but if you care, I'm using [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) with a Rails 4.0 app.

Using jQuery, I send my app a `PATCH` request like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://example.com/whatever",
  type: "PATCH",
  data: { something: "something else" }
})
```

When I trigger this call from Chrome, I see a successful `OPTIONS` request go out, which returns these headers from my server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sending-app.localhost:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Access-Control-Max-Age:15
```

Then I see a `PATCH` request go out, which throws this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/whatever. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sending-app.localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I have tried switching from `PATCH` to `PUT` with the same results.

This doesn't make any sense to me. What's going on?

#### Update: My config/application.rb

I thought the headers told the whole story, but since people are confused, here's my `config/application.rb` file, which is how the rack-cors plugin for Rails is configured:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:get, :put, :patch, :options],
      :max_age => 15
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your `application.rb` look like?

Comment: @RichPeck I've added my `application.rb`, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exclude Rails CSRF checking in the action ;)

That is, Rails checks for an authenticity token with update/create requests. Within your Rails app, this token is added to all of your forms. But with javascript requests, including it is tricky.

You can skip checking it for an action by adding this to your controller:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:update]
```

BTW, your problem had nothing to do with CORS, you were getting a bad error message in the browser. The Rails log tells the *real* story.

Comment: Why the -1? This was the fix for the issue. The request is coming from a separate app with no knowledge of the CSRF token.

Comment: Because the solution is to disable csrf. That sounds like a security hole. However, if it is an authenticated request that sounds alright.

Comment: Fair enough. You can't expect users of an external service to provide a CSRF token. This is being trigger from one app, while the endpoint lives in another app, so it's going across domains. If it was all within the same app, I would agree with you.

Comment: Fast forward to 2018 and its now `skip_before_action` with Rails 5 (and technically with Rails 4 too).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to add this to your `config/application.rb` file:

```
#config/application.rb
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '/*', :headers => :any, :methods => :patch
  end
end
```

The `resource` part is where you define which methods / requests your endpoint can accept!

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, I thought just showing the headers returned would indicate that I had already done this. This is an issue of HTTP headers, not Rails config, so I wanted to keep the question generally accessible and not clutter it with unnecessary Rails stuff. I've now added my `rack-cors` setup that I have in config/application.rb.

Comment: Thanks bud - what environment are you seeing this error on? Production and/or development? Can you describe the setup?

Comment: I'm seeing this in production, which is on Heroku. It's pretty close to vanilla Rails 4; `rack-cors` is the only Rack middleware I've added.

Comment: Strange - we've been working with Heroku production for a while, and have this functionality working. Have you got your routes & controller action set up to handle the request?

Comment: I sure do! I have specs on this `PATCH` endpoint and it does everything I'd like it to do.

Comment: Any chance you could try another method other than `patch`? What about `post` (just as a test)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43706/discussion-between-chadoh-and-rich-peck)

Answer (score 1):

This is some strange stuff.

A) As a trial you should try entering in `*` as your allowed origin.

B) Is this a whitespace issue? After the colons you don't have spaces in some of the options.

C) This looks like a "preflighted request" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). A preflighted request is one that doesn't use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded," which yours should be. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ states the default content type is x-www-form-urlencoded, and you aren't overriding content type. That means there shouldn't need to be 2 requests.

D) As noted above, CSRF might be the issue. I am not a rails person. If it is the issue what you may want to do is attach your CSRF token to all ajax sends like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
    beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '<%= csrf_token_value %>');
    } 
});
```

There are a few other ways to do this. It depends what your frameworks/libraries need.

Comment: That would be fine if the request wasn't coming from a completely different app. We've on the same team at work and CSRF is the issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found to solve the issue from older SO posts to deal with csrf issues:

```
# In application_controller.rb
protect_from_forgery

after_filter :set_csrf_cookie

def set_csrf_cookie
  cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery?
end

protected

# In Rails 4.2 and above
def verified_request?
  super || valid_authenticity_token?(session, request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'])
end
```