# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cors

I am out of ideas.  I made a small app for a friend who is using it in a school.  As long as it is on non-school internet, it works fine.  At school, though, there are two buttons that don't work.  They both are making an ajax request to a different controller.  They give a no access-control-allow-origin header error.  I have tried every fix that I can find, and nothing will work.  I am out of ideas.  The current iteration involves the rack-cors gem, which I have below.  I have also tried the fixes at 
[CORS issue: Getting error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" when it actually is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724470/cors-issue-getting-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-w), [XMLHttpRequest No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045681/xmlhttprequest-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-request), http://www.yihangho.com/rails-cross-origin-resource-sharing/, and http://leopard.in.ua/2012/07/08/using-cors-with-rails/. Is there anything else I can do?

config.ru

```
require 'rack/cors'
use Rack::Cors do

  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
        :headers => :any,
        :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options, :patch]
  end
end
```

application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
   allow do
     origins '*'
     resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :options, :put]
   end
end
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: No access-control-allow-origin header is present on request resource. Origin (my domain name) is therefore not allowed

Comment: I'll write an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

[CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is designed to prevent cross domain XML requests.

I'm not sure as to the specific reasons for this, but the short of it is that if you try and hit an external domain with Ajax (without CORS permissions granted), it will be denied.

> As long as it is on non-school internet, it works fine

<s>Yep, because the "domain" will be considered "local"</s> Sorry I misread that as "Intranet".

This will depend on the server you're accessing - you need to make sure the server has CORS enabled.

---

I've dealt with a similar issue to you before.

You've done the right thing by using [`rack-cors`](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors):

```
#config/application.rb
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
   allow do
       origins '*' #-> has to be "*" or specific
       resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
   end
end
```

If you're using this (remember, you have to **restart your server** to get it working), it *should* work.

The main considerations for CORS are the `origin` and `resource` - they either have to be "*" (all), or explicitly defined (IE `google.com` or something).

In your case, allowing them "all" should be okay to test - you'll then need to ensure you have the specific domain defined.

Comment: I had tried restarting the server, still not working. Why would internet at one place consider the domain local, but at a school it wouldn't?